# How to convert List<ClassModel> to List<string> easily

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, serialization

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 WebAPI which contains a class model called `ImagePath` that has one property only called `filename`, my problem is how can I convert or map a list of this class to list of string.. I mean it takes the property `filename` and add it to a list of string BUT without using any kind of loops (for, foreach, while..)

The data that comes from the API

```
"images": [
    {
        "filename": "6f2290d2-c26f-4132-b7dc-c70ca3bbadb5.jpg"
    },
    {
        "filename": "8057c245-d980-40b5-964e-5fda69684300.jpg"
    },
    {
        "filename": "a085f172-e711-4520-abab-1defc8e9dde8.jpg"
    },
    {
        "filename": "db5c2296-0679-4e02-9e34-674aaa578be8.jpg"
    }
],
```

what I want is this

```
"images": [
    "6f2290d2-c26f-4132-b7dc-c70ca3bbadb5.jpg",
    "8057c245-d980-40b5-964e-5fda69684300.jpg",
    "a085f172-e711-4520-abab-1defc8e9dde8.jpg",
    "db5c2296-0679-4e02-9e34-674aaa578be8.jpg"
],
```

Any solutions?

Comment: "without using any kind of loops (for, foreach, while..)" Why that? If you want to get all values, you have to query all of them. This usually is done by **iterating** the members in some way. Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve? Anyway you can use a JSON-serializer, e.g. NewtonSoft, to get data from JSON ir write data to JSON.

Comment: `var stringList = classList.Select(x => x.filename).ToList();`. This will still iterate over all of the items though, there's probably no way around that.

Comment: There's no such thing as "without loops."  Linq runs loops under the covers.

Comment: @devNull You know this also iterates the collection? As Robert already pointed out: "without loops" is pretty pointless requirement.

Comment: Why no loops?  This can help us answer better.

Comment: @HimBromBeere well, I meant by not using those only (for, foreach, while) directly BUT not at all, I knew that there should be a way doing it better like as others and you said by using SELECT for instance, THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: @devNull Thank you so much dear

Comment: @RobertHarvey I meant only using the loops I mentioned like (for, foreach, while) but this is what I wanted .. the SELECT is what I was looking for .

Comment: @Markuzy see comments above I explained it clearly, and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

listClassModel.Select(p => p.filename).ToList()